# Oversized Windows CE forms in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I'm developing a Windows CE CF3.5 application under Visual Studio 2008, everything went smooth until the designer started throwing a `NullReferenceException`. Restarted VS2008, rebooted Win7 and the exception disappeared but all the forms for the project I was working on and new projects that I tested have this aspect:

[image]

On the emulator it varies, it either appears really tiny in the upper left corner or it displays correctly:

[image]

Any ideas? I've googled for this to no success. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the solution explorer, expand your form and open the Form.Designer.cs file.

Have a look and try altering the `AutoScale` and `AutoScaleDimensions` properties

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that functionality. Anyway, it had the `AutoScaleMode` set to Dpi and the `AutoScaleDimensions` to the correct dimensions by default. Altering this values did not have any impact on the Form representation on the emulator though.

Comment: After a VS restart the `AutoScaleMode` set to `Inherited` gave its fruits, it appears as it should again. thanks!

Comment: Half of it at least!:) The form on design mode is still messed up. Tried to rate your answer, but I don't have enough points.

Answer (score 0):

Like every good programmer you use some kind of Source Control (VSS, SVN, Git, etc.).

So simply make a diff of your current not working version and your last working one and see what changed.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, I did the diff, the only thing that changed was some controls names and a new DataGrid. I believe this issue may be related to some global configuration: if I create a new Win CE Forms Project the layout of the form is also distorted.